# How can I measure the effects certain events have on the frequency of other events over time?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, signal-processing, change-point, intervention-analysis

**EDIT: added more details following @kjetil comments**

I have the following problem:

- I monitor one stream of events of type A - those events can be considered instantaneous.
- I also monitor additional streams of events of types B1, B2,... Bn - those have a time interval associated with them.
- I want to determine if the frequency of type A events *increases* significantly during any specific B types (in other words, I want to determine exactly which B types have a significant *positive* influence during the intervals of their events)
- Many instances of the same type of event can occur simultaneously
- The effect is likely to be linear in the number of concurrent events of the specific B type
- There are probably many B types that don't effect A-events
- B types of events are not necessarily the only thing that influence type A events
- All events probably have some complex distribution that changes depending on the day/hour/week/month/previous events - not a simple Poisson
- I *constantly* monitor all streams - I want to discover when a B-type starts to influence the frequency of A-event and I would also want to know if at some point in the future it stopped influence it (and this should continue indefinitely))

For example:

- A-type events are power outages
- B1-type events correspond to opening and closing of air conditioners.
- B2-type events correspond to opening and closing of televisions.

Do you have any idea how I should approach this problem? (general references are fine)

Comment: Why don't you post some actual data and I will try and apply time series methods including Intervention Detection procedures.

Comment: @IrishStat - I'm trying to outline a work-plan for creating a program... I don't have data yet and even if I had, the program still needs to be robust enough to handle data that may behave considerably different. 
So basically I'm just trying to understand what are the most generic sensible approaches to this problem.
More specifically, you've mentioned time-series methods and intervention detection... :) I'm looking into those, but I still didn't quite manage to understand how I should apply them in this case (started reading books on the time-series analysis just a few days ago)

Comment: Well you could always generate data according to a known/specified structure where some covariates were important and others not subject to your specification. The data could then be augmented with an error process , not necessarily indpendently distributed which could potentially mask the underlying DGF. You could also augment/perturb your output series with level shifts / time trends or holiday effects (pre and post ). This kind of data , although artificial , could teach you about how to deal with i.e. analyze real data.

Comment: @IrisihStat - I get that in order to give a high quality robust answer I need to get a statistician and do a lot more analysis... but since that's not in the budget (just got a few CS researchers with bad CS research methodologies). I'd appreciate it if you could point to relevant topics/suggest references. Note that the program doesn't have to be perfect (and can't, because of the difference in data sources). Anything better than doing a z-test on the frequency of A during some B (using the mean and variance of A frequency) is a good place to start.
In any case, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you do it wrong ...or less wrong. I would have no idea about these references that you request.

Comment: Hey the engineers often do not-so-good statistics and live with it... at least I'm trying to understand how to do it right :) (given time-constraints). Anyway I do appreciate that you tried to help. @IrishStat

Comment: You say "I'm trying to outline a work-plan for creating a program" again my approach is to create a dataset that has "complications" , sprinkle some noise on it , then provide the data to some analyst WITHOUT telling them exactly how the data was created.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas: For an initial analysis, you should make some plots. I suppose the main interest is in the possible dependence of intensity of A-events upon if the event occurs when a B-event is active or not. You could start with making a simple plot: on the y-axis you plot the cumulated number of A-events $n_A(t)$, on the x-axis you represent the time $t$, but you mark on the axis with a heavier line when an B-event is active. Then you can overplot with some smoother, and look to see if the slope seems to be different when B is active than when not. You could go further, make a smooth also of the derivative of the smoothed curve (with splines this can be done automatically, I think for the curve + its first derivative, a quintic spline is good. One possibility is to use the R package gss, but there are certainly others). When this is done, you can plot a histogram of (samples of) the smoothed derivative sampled at points $0,\delta t, 2\delta t, 3 \delta t, \dots $ within the two groups defined by B-event on or off.

Then for a model, you could base a simple model on the poisson process. Then we would need to go into how to calculate (or first define) a likelihood function for a poisson process. To avoid that, we do something simpler: Divide the t-axis (x-axis in the above plot) into small intervals. If the poisson process model is correct, the number of counts in each interval will be independent. Adjust so that each interval is completely B-event or not-B-event. count number of A-ponts in each interval. Fit a poisson regression (in R with the function glm()), with the interval length as an offset.

Of course, after doing this, you will need to investigate if the Poisson process assumption holds: Check for overdispersion, make a plot of interarrival times, which should be exponentially distributed (drop the times which takes the time between two A-points with different value of B), plot this separately for B and not-B, check if this seems to be exponential (you can do a density estimate).

For more ideas see the simple little book:
"The statistical analysis of stochastic processes in time" by J K LIndsey, which is downloadable (legally!). google for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! a few questions: (1) why use the derivative function and not just the average frequency of A-events? (2) assuming that counting the number of A in B and non-B intervals gives me 2 Poisson distributions - how do I compare the two? (your answer is helpful- but, I actually have additional limitations: (1) events probably depend on each other (Poisson?) (2) got an infinite automatic process (a monitoring program) (3) few B-events can happen in the same time (4) I can't really measure non-B intervals- I actually monitor many types of B-events).

Comment: Also, thanks for the book reference, I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: I think you should give some more details. How many different B-events are there?  What do you measn by"I cannot really measure non-B" ¿Cant you o9bserve a-points when some B-event not are active? Again, we need more details! As for the monitoring, as soon as we have a working model we can look into it! Maybe the CRAN package strucchange?

Comment: Hi after giving it some thiught - that last comment (4) is wrong - I have thousands of A types and B types so I don't currently count A-non-B frequency - but with right implementation I can save all the frequencies.  As for the package -maybe it can help but I still need to understand what type of analysis I should do...

Comment: Yes, but the situation is obviously much more complex than your originally simple description seems to apply, so we do need more details ...

Comment: OK, I've edited the original question. I hope it is more clear now. @kjetil

Comment: OK. I see from your comments above you do not really have data yet. You are describibg a very complex situation, and you do not really seem to have the statistical knowledge neccessary to model it well. Some advice: start with simple models, such as poisson-based, even if you expect them to be rejected by your data. Use goodness-of-fit techniques to study how your data depart from those assumptions.  And contact some statistician!!!

Comment: Statisticians are not likely to come to the rescue (see the comment I wrote to IrishStat). Thanks for your help, I get that this is a complex problem that requires expertise. In any case, I'd appreciate any pointers/guidelines/references you can think of (BTW, I'm still in the process of checking the book you've mentioned..). Thanks again. @kjetil

Comment: I look intoif there are some other good sources you could look into!  If your budget is to lpw that is obviously a problem. Maybe this is a specialised problem that not every statistician would be able to help (every phD statistician would be able!) But ask for somebody with experience in survival analysis, they might help. With such a complex problem one needs to sit at the same table and discuss!

Comment: some pointers:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_process

Comment: some pointers:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_process     This looks interesting and could give you ideas:  http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2012/07/11/1203177109.abstract                      This could help:    http://www.core.ucl.ac.be/econometrics/Bauwens/papers/HighFrequencyData_HFTS_Rev2_Ver3.pdf           Most books on point processes are highly mathemathical, I guess this one might be more accesible than most:    http://www.amazon.com/Processes-Chapman-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/0412219107/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1356364136&sr=1-1&keywords=point+processes

Comment: Hey @kjetil, thanks for the references. It's complicated stuff but I'm getting there. Perhaps at some point in the far future I can post an answer to my question.